# How can I calculate total when I add new input field using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".price2").keyup(function(){
       total = parseInt($(".price1").val()) + parseInt($(".price2").val());
       $(".total").val(total);
   });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="price1" >
<input type="text" class="price2" >
<input type="text" class="total" >
```

This Code Snippet Perform addition of two field and add total to third. ok this looks good but the problem is when i add new field using jQuery so total wont work. what should i have to do to add total even when i add new input field using jQuery

*You can understand better by following image*
[image]

I Add New Field By following code

```
var i = 0;
   $("#addmore").click(function() {
     $("#inputtabletable tr:first").clone().find(".webfield").each(function() {
       $(this).val('').attr({
         'id': function(_, id) {
           return id + i
         },
         'name': function(_, name) {
           return name + i
         },
         'value': ''
       });
     }).end().appendTo("#inputtabletable");
     i++;
   });
```

How can i add total when i add new field using jQuery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your use case, requires some changes to your html and javascript, it wouldn't work out of the box. you need to make use of event delegation and capture the events from an element that is created in the future.

More Information on delegates can be found here [jQuery .on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.addition').on('keyup', '.price', function() {
    var total = 0
    $('.addition > .price').each(function() {
      var currentValue = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
      if (!isNaN(currentValue)) {
        total += currentValue;
      }
    });
    $(".total").val(total);
  });
  $('.add').click(function() {
    $("<input type='text' class='price'>").appendTo($('.addition'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='addition'>
  <input type="text" class="price">
  <input type="text" class="price">
</div>
Total: <input type="text" class="total">
<button class='add'>Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Sreekanth's answer of using delegates is probably a better way to do this. Leaving this here as an alternative

You will have to dynamically create elements which share a common class name and use the class to compute the sum. You may also have to register/unregister events each time a new element is created to prevent multiple handlers being registerd.

Sample Implementation:

```js
function createItem() {
  var $item = $('<div><input type="text" value="" class="item"/></div>');
  return $item;
}

function registerListeners() {
  $('.item').off('keyup',calculateTotal);
  $('.item').on('keyup',calculateTotal);
}

function calculateTotal() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.item').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    total += isNaN(value) ? 0 : (+value);
  });
  $('#total').html(total);
}
$(function() {
  var $container = $('#container');
  $('#new').click(function() {
    var $newItem = createItem();
    $container.append($newItem);
    registerListeners();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

</div>
<div>
  <div>Total: <span id="total"></span></div>
  <button id="new">Add new item</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

//HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-new-field">Add New Field</button>
<div class="container">
<input type="text" class="price" value="0">
<input type="text" class="price" value="0" >

</div>
<input type="text" class="total" >
```

// Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#add-new-field").on('click',AddNewField);  $("body").on('keyup','.price',function(){
     calculateTotal();
   });

});

function calculateTotal()
{
  var total=0;
  $(".price").each(function(i,v){
    if($(v).val()!="")
    total+=parseFloat($(v).val());
  })
  $(".total").val(total);
}

function AddNewField()
{
  $(".container").append("<input class='price' value='0'>");
}
```